# Ошибка атрибутов модуля PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, pil

При попытке использовать метод: image.convert('RGBA'), вылезает ошибка: AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'convert'.
Вот кусочек кода, отвечающий за это:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь вызвать метод `convert` не у объекта изображения, а у подмодуля `PIL`.

Не знаю, какое конкретно из изображений вам нужно конвертировать, но из вашего кода это можно сделать либо с:

```
img = Image.new('RGBA', (500, 250), '#3145')
img.convert('RGBA')
```

либо с:

```
response = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
response.convert('RGBA')
```

*На будущее - лучше не называйте разные переменные одинаково, это обязательно приведёт к ошибкам (3 разных переменных с названием response), в каждой строке заново переопределять переменную не нужно. Ну и, пожалуйста, выкладывайте в вопросе сам код, а не его скриншот.*